# Unable to Deploy an application to Oracle Java Cloud Service - "Cloud App Compile" complete: status FAILED

Tags: java, weblogic, paas, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I'm building a simple java application, mainly trying to connect to the DBCS using the JNDI name. Below is the error seen while trying to deploy the application to JCS from JDeveloper.

Please note the application works fine in the Integrated weblogic server. 
Error log below shows an `IllegalArgumentException` at the Cloud App compile stage. I'm not sure what might be causing the issue.

**Update: I'm unable to deploy the JDeveloper project if it contains even a simple HelloWorld java class which is not referenced anywhere else (like a JSP). So its nothing related to my code. Could this be an issue with the settings in my JDeveloper or an issue with the Oracle Cloud weblogic server itself ? 
I'm creating a profile to deploy the project to Oracle Cloud WLServer as a WAR.

Please help.

> [01:03:08 PM] 2016-03-03 01:32:53 CST: WebLogic Application
>   Compilation succeeded
>
> [01:03:08 PM] 2016-03-03 01:32:53 CST: "WLS App Compile" complete:
>   status SUCCESS
>
> [01:03:08 PM] 2016-03-03 01:32:53 CST: Starting action "Cloud App
>   Compile"
>
> [01:03:08 PM] 2016-03-03 01:32:53 CST: Cloud App Compile started
>
> [01:03:08 PM] Failure Message:Cloud-Appc FailedLog:
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Unzipping at ****
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Detecting all class files ...
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Injecting 774 class(es) ...
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Generating glue code at:****
>
> [01:03:08 PM] intermediate****
>
> [01:03:08 PM] SecurityManager_RPKNV82485aazka.java
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [ERROR]   - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>
> [01:03:08 PM] |
>
> [01:03:08 PM] +----> Caused By : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>
> [01:03:08 PM]
>
> [01:03:08 PM] Error(s) - Process exited with code:4
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Unzipping at ****
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Detecting all class files ...
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Injecting 774 class(es) ...
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [INFO]    - Generating glue code at:****
>
> [01:03:08 PM] intermediate****
>
> [01:03:08 PM] SecurityManager_RPKNV82485aazka.java
>
> [01:03:08 PM] [ERROR]   - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>
> [01:03:08 PM] |
>
> [01:03:08 PM] +----> Caused By : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>
> [01:03:08 PM]
>
> [01:03:08 PM] 2016-03-03 01:33:03 CST: Cloud Application Compilation
>   failed
>
> [01:03:08 PM] 2016-03-03 01:33:03 CST: "Cloud App Compile" complete:
>   status  FAILED
>
> [01:03:08 PM] ----- End Oracle Cloud Deploy Log -----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with using the JDeveloper version - Oracle recommends using JDev 11.1.1.7 instead of JDev 12c for deployment to JCS-SX

Comment: Could you accept this answer so others can see that the question has been resolved?